# C++ Iterator Syntax

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm confused about C++ syntax for instantiating an iterator namely (for a list),

```
std::list<C++ class object>::iterator iterator_name;
```

What is up with `std::list` before the `::iterator`, does this mean `iterator` is defined in a namespace `list` in `std`?

Sorry if this question is obvious or trivial, but I've finally convinced myself to use "std" more and now I'm finding some of the syntax to be a bit confusing.

Comment: It's a specific iterator for std::list, so it's defined within that scope. You can't assign an iterator for a vector to it, for example (the way you iterate depends on the data structure)

Comment: I'm usually not saying this, but [RTFM](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list). In this particular case I don't consider this comment _being rude_.

Comment: I did read the manual on http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/, I just didn't know at the time you needed to access iterator as :: instead of something like -> or .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterator` is an **embedded member type** of the class template `std::list`. `std` is the Standard Library namespace.

The **scope resolution operator `::`** is used to access names in namespaces and classes, the documentation (or source code) should be consulted to get an exact definition of the name.

---

In this case, `iterator` is an embedded type for most Standard Library containers. It is often also used for containers that are modelled on the Standard Library, but it is not a general requirement for any given class.

Answer (score 9):

It is a **member type**. The `std::list` template class is (conceptually) defined as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class list {
public:
    using iterator = /* some implementation-dependent type */
};
```

Hence, regardless of the standard library implementation you are using, you know that, for some `T`, `std::list<T>::iterator` is an alias for the type implementing the list iterator.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list<>` is not a namespace, it's a template class, and `iterator` is a type inside this template. To access it, you use the double colons.

Comment: It's a template class.

Comment: @NeilKirk - You mean template class and not "type"? Or you mean template class, not template?

Comment: `std::list` is a template class.

Comment: OK... Semantics *are* important in this case, so thanks for fine tuning me :-)

Comment: `std::list` is a _class template_. `std::list<T[, A]>` is a class.

Answer (score 3):

`std::list` is a template class. Saying `std::list< T >::iterator` means you have an iterator of a list and not an iterator of a vector (`std::vector< T >::iterator`) or any other container.

If you find the name too long you can also use `auto` if you initialize the iterator:

```
auto it = myList.begin();
```

Answer (score 0):

**std::list::iterator obj_iterator;  // It means declaring pointer  obj_iterator of type std::list**

```
//simple code snippet
    std::list<int> intList; // declaring intList of type std::list<int>
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        intList.push_back( 1 << i ); 
    }
    std::list<int>::iterator int_iterator;  //declaring pointer int_iterator of type std::list<int>

    for (int_iterator = intList.begin(); int_iterator != intList.end(); ++int_iterator) {
    std::cout << *int_iterator;    // using of int_iterator
    }`
```